# Connecting to a remote Windows machine

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote-connection

I was given a remote machine address along with a username and password.

But I cannot connect via Remote Desktop, nor after pasting the address into the address bar of Explorer.

All I know about the specifics of the server is that I have to get some files from a "file repo"?

Comment: What details do you know about the remote machine? Are you on the same physical network or do you need to go through a RDG (Remote Desktop Gateway)? What version of Windows are you running on your machine? The file(s) from the file repo may be a certificate for the RDG? Do the people you're connecting to have documentation? Sorry for all the questions just trying to get as much info as possible to better help you.

Comment: Yes, I should have engaged brains before asking...

I just entered  

    //[address]

in the file browser and I got connected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from you comment that you were just trying to navigate to the sever's file shares (and not having to remote onto it.) So I'll formalize and answer here (it sounds like you're already there.)

To access the server's files shares enter the server's address into Windows Explorer in the form of:

```
\\<servername>
```

If you require to sign in to access the shares a dialogue box will pop up at this stage.